# how to change button style onclick in angular?

Tags: angular

I need to change the button style when click event is triggered.

I browsed and found out to use `[class]` property but not sure how to implement it. I need to call a css class once click event is triggered.

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="isdisabled"
   style="background: #79CEA4 !important;color: #FFFFFF !important;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 600;margin-right: 10px"
   class="btn  btn-lg"  (click)="start(tId,uId)"> START
</button>
```

Comment: Why not use :hover, :focus, :active in css?

Comment: you want this class to be active only when it's being clicked? Or if it has been clicked once?

Comment: @Powkachu i want to disable this button,but there is already one disable property .So i thought to providing the button colour to grey and pointer-events to none.I need to do this if the button is clicked

Comment: @Hosh Do you mean in inspect element ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a toggle variable in .ts (clicked: boolean), and set true, in the click event handler method.

Next, add this attribute to HTML element:

```
 [ngClass]="{'your-class' : clicked}"
```

It append the css class list with the given class name if the clicked variable is true.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example when use the click `event`.

```html
<button
        type="button"
        [disabled]="isdisabled"
        style="
          background: #79cea4 !important;
          color: #ffffff !important;
          font-size: 13px;
          font-weight: 600;
          margin-right: 10px;
        "
        class="btn btn-lg"
        (click)="start($event,tId,uId)"
        >START</button>
```

Now, in your `typescript` and method `start`, you can use this example below:

```js
start(event: MouseEvent & { target: HTMLElement }, tId, uId): void {
    console.log('start');

    // change style
    event.target.style.background = 'orange';

    // add class
    event.target.classList.add('example-class');
  }
```

That code above just an example. Because you can use `[ngClass]` or `[ngStyle]`. It's your choice.

Comment: please, use "Angular way". Remember: in Angular you have variables in .ts and use this variables in the .html, You can use `[ngClass]` or `[class]` or `[ngStyle]` or `[style.property]`

Comment: Please read my answer above, I've been said that is an example. But you can use [ngClass] and [ngStyle]. I think there's no wrong with that answer, beacuase point of that question is how to change the button style.

Comment: Titus, you can change the background in severals ways, In my personal opinion, using event.target.style.background or event.target.classList.add are not "enought closer" to Angular (and the question is about Angular), but it's only my personal opinion.